# How to find the degree- n term in the Maclaurin polynomial of $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> How to find the degree- n term in the Maclaurin polynomial of
>   $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$?

**My Thoughts:**

The nth term is obviously:

$$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

**But I am stuck here, how do I find the nth derivative of the function $\ln(1+x)$?**

Comment: Start to calculate derivatives, there will be a nice pattern.

Comment: Use the geometric series for $\frac {1}{1+x}$ and then integrate term by term.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks :) Il give it a shot

Comment: You are welcome. If you run into trouble I can help, but I think the pattern will be clear. There will be alternations of signs.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yep it is $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(1+x)^n n!}$$ right? Therefore at x=0, the nth term is $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}$$

Comment: There are some errors. The $n$-th derivative is $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How did you get the $(n-1)!$ term?

Comment: I will write an answer, since lots of math in comments is tough to type.

Comment: @AndréNicolas For sure :) Thanks alot Andre :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start differentiating. We have
$f'(x)=(1+x)^{-1}$, $f''(x)=-(1+x)^{-2}$, $f'''(x)=(-1)(-2)(1+x)^{-3}$, $f^{(4)}(x)=(-1)(-2)(-3)(1+x)^{-4}$, $f^{(5)}(x)=(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)(1+x)^{-5}$, $f^{(6)}(x)=(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)(-5)(1+x)^{-6}$,and so on.

The pattern is clear: $f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!(1+x)^{-n}$.

It follows that $f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!$.

If $n\ge 1$, the coefficient of $x^n$ is therefore $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!}{n!}$. This simplifies to $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$. Note that the constant term is $0$.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I understood now :)